# Can も replace を when used with 気にしない

Tags: syntax

For example I want to say

> 俺は彼だったらあなたも気にしない

I know that it should be `あなたを気にしない`, but I couldn't find it being used this way anywhere online in the meaning "didn't care ABOUT you, too". にも yields no results whatsoever

If I say it like above, would it be correct grammatically?

Comment: It’s syntactically correct, except 俺は should be 俺が. But I cannot tell if the sentence says what you want to say. What exactly do you want to say? Do you mean you wouldn’t care about the person addressed as “you” just like you wound’t care about other people, or you also wouldn’t care about that person just like “he” doesn’t?

Comment: @aguijonazo sorry for not including my thought in English. I'm trying to say "If I were him, I wouldn't care about you, too". And the nuance I'm trying to include here is that "too"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking purely about syntax, replacing を with も is not a problem at all.

However, your sentence has several other issues.

First of all, あなたを気にしない is not quite idiomatic. あなた**のこと**を気にしない sounds much more natural. Besides, or perhaps because of this reason, あなたも気にしない would most likely be understood as:

> You don’t care, either.

Secondly, 俺は should be 俺**が**. This は takes out 俺 as a topic, but a topic usually doesn’t go inside a subordinate clause.

After these corrections (and a comma for readability), we arrive at the following:

> 俺が彼だったら、あなたのことを気にしない。

Though this sounds natural enough, I would prefer:

> 俺が彼なら、あなたのことを気にしない。

Let’s agree on this as the base sentence to which to add the meaning of も, for the sake of the following discussion.

Now, I understand what you want to say is:

> If I were him, I wouldn’t care about you, either.

However, there is a little ambiguity to this English sentence because it could be interpreted in, at least, two ways:

> 1. He doesn’t care about you. If I were him, I wouldn’t care about you, either. [i.e. I am like him.]

or

> 2. He may not care about other people, but he cares about you. If I were him, I wouldn’t care about you, either. [i.e. You are like other people (for me).]

This ambiguity needs to be resolved if the above sentence is to be translated to Japanese.

Your approach of replacing を with も would result:

> 俺が彼なら、あなたのことも気にしない。

This works only in the second scenario.

In the first scenario, も would have to go with 俺 because that's what you want to put into the same group as something else, which is the main function of も. One straightforward solution would be to make the subject of the main clause, which is 俺, explicit and add も to it, like this.

> 俺が彼なら、俺もあなたのことを気にしない。

However, this sounds not only redundant but also a bit unnatural because 俺が彼なら somewhat suggests what follows will talk about some contrast between “me” and “him”, yet the main clause contradicts it.

It would be more natural to say:

> 俺が彼でも、あなたのことを気にしない。

This would be interpreted as meaning either one of the following:

> 1. He doesn’t care about you. In his shoes, I also wouldn’t care about you.

or

> 2. I don’t care about you. Even in his shoes, I still wouldn’t care about you.

Some ambiguity remains, but context will take care of the rest.